# Collection size extension funcion

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to implement a extension function which if the collection size is bigger than some value it runs some code block but I get this error in the `Collection<*>` part:

> Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter

the code:

```
fun <C, R> C.ifBiggerThan(size: Int, execute: () -> R): R where C : Collection<*>, C : R  =
        if (this.size > size) { execute() } else { this }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's tricky to work around, but what potential type of R are you anticipating that would be different than C? Can you get away with using a single type parameter of type Collection?

Comment: It looks like you ought to be able to simply replace `R` with `C`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 for now I'm expecting to throw an exception, but I think its useful to have a more generalized function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `if` branch you return `R`, in `else` branch you return `C`. Type of the resulting expression is the most specific supertype of `if` and `else` branches. In this case it will be `R`, because `C : R`. So there is no point in introducing `C` type as an extension of `R`. Type of the resulting expression will still be `R`. So, you may just substitute it as a `Collection<T>`:

```kotlin
fun <T> Collection<T>.ifBiggerThan(size: Int, execute: () -> Collection<T>): Collection<T> =
    if (this.size > size) { execute() } else { this }
```